Errors with starting Windows Subsystem for Linux after installation
I have just installed WSL and tried to run it after a reboot but get errors. Am I understanding something not correctly?
In the PowerShell, run as an administrator:
PS C:\Users\Marcel> wsl.exe --install

After the apparently successful installation and reboot:
PS C:\Users\Marcel> wsl -v -l
WSL version: 2.0.14.0
Kernel version: 5.15.133.1-1
WSLg version: 1.0.59
MSRDC version: 1.2.4677
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.19045.5011

PS C:\Users\Marcel> wsl -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
  Ubuntu                 Stopped         2

PS C:\Users\Marcel> wsl
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: CreateProcessParseCommon:708: Failed to translate C:\Users\Marcel
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: CreateProcessParseCommon:754: getpwuid(0) failed 2
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Player\bin\
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64_win\compiler
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Windows\system32
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Windows
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\WINDOWS\system32
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\WINDOWS
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Program Files\dotnet\
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Program Files (x86)\Touch Portal\plugins\adb\platform-tools
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Tools\Binn\
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\WolframScript\
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Program Files\Calibre2\
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Ruby32-x64\bin
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Users\Marcel\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.2.1\bin
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Users\Marcel\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Users\Marcel\AppData\Roaming\Programs\Zero Install
Processing fstab with mount -a failed.
Failed to mount C:\, see dmesg for more details.
Failed to mount D:\, see dmesg for more details.
Failed to mount G:\, see dmesg for more details.

<3>WSL (11) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:331: getpwuid(0) failed 2
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:502: execvpe /bin/sh failed 2
<3>WSL (11) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:505: Create process not expected to return

Shouldn't WSL in the PowerShell boot it?

Just to check: Have you looked up how to start WSL? It may just be a language/phrasing thing, but it sounds as though you're not sure how to start it. If that is the case, yes, running wsl is how you start WSL, and you can see from your logs that WSL is trying to start, so your problem is not that it isn't TRYING to start, but that it is trying and FAILING. So we need to figure out why it is failing.
